# Can I Localize my app for a language which is not supported by iPhone?

Tags: ios4, ios5, localization

I want to develop a multi lingual app in iPhone which should support English and Irish. But I just get to know that there is no Irish language in the iPhone setting. So I wanted to know how can I add Irish support to my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a developer, you can make your app do anything, including showing the text in any way you like. What you won't be able to do is use Apple's built-in tools, which rely on the system settings to determine a user's language and push the text from a Localizable.strings file.

You could, however, make a setting inside your app where you offer to switch languages. As far as your texts, you're going to want to use the same basic logic as any localization system:

1) Surround all in-app text in a function that displays either English or Irish based on the user's chosen settings
2) Export your English strings into a file
3) Translate the English strings to Irish in a separate file

The function you write can be similar to what [gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) does. If the settings is "Irish" pull the equivalent string from the Irish file. If the setting is English, just print the English.

Although you won't be able to use Apple's tools, you can quickly recreate this functionality on the basic logic of Gettext to accomplish the same thing.

If you choose to localize into an Apple-supported language, follow this [app localization tutorial for iOS](http://www.ibabbleon.com/iphone_app_localization.html).